# Correct usage of spring @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-bean

I'm working on a jax-rs project for an RESTFul API

I choose to use spring in order to automatically inject my dependencies

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;
```

And here is my spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Manager -->
    <bean id="userManager" class="com.mypackage.manager.UserManagerImpl"/>
    <bean id="cardManager" class="com.mypackage.manager.CardManagerImpl"/>
    <bean id="albumManager" class="com.mypackage.manager.AlbumManagerImpl"/>

    <!-- Dao -->
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.mypackage.dao.UserDaoImpl"/>
    <bean id="cardDao" class="com.mypackage.dao.CardDaoImpl"/>

    <!-- Session factory for hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="file:web/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But I got a NullPointerException here :

```
userManager.getUserById(1);
```

And here is the code of the method :

```
public UserDto getUserById(Integer userId) throws NotFoundException {
    /*User user = userDao.findById(userId);*/
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("creekorful");
    user.setAvatarUrl("myavatar/avatar.image");
    user.setEmail("creekorful@gmail.com");
    user.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVATED);
    user.setAccountType(AccountType.ADMINISTRATOR);
    return new UserDto(user);
}
```

Is there all I need to make spring automatically instantiate and inject my manager? Because no matter what soluce I try to use, It seems that my userManager is still null. I think i'm missing something about the functionnement of spring...

N.B : I've put my spring.xml into my WEB-INF/class directory in my .war

Thank in advance

Comment: I wouldn't mix annotations and XML based config. Choose one or the other.

Comment: I prefer annotations. But aren't XML config needed to register the beans?

Comment: You don't need any XML config for anything.

Comment: So how do I specify the injection? How do I configure spring ?

Comment: Any recent tutorial would show you how to do full annotation config. If you're using [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html) it's easy peasy, otherwise you need to configure the `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

In your spring.xml, you'll also need to ensure that you've enabled annotations like so:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I've added that line to my spring.XML, but sadly nothing has changed... Am I'm missing something ?

Comment: In your bean definition, you have the class set to UserManagerImpl. Shouldn't it just be UserManager, since that is the type of the field you're trying to autowire?

Comment: I'm gonna try this. But I'm thinking that the bean should point to the implementation of my user manager interface rather than the interface

Comment: Yep don't work, "Interface not allowed for non abstract bean"

Comment: Should my UserManager have a public empty constructor?

Comment: You can try it (I assume you mean your implementation of the user manager interface).

Comment: Sadly doesnt work... got a NullPointerException at : userManager.getUserById();

Comment: Can you post your full spring.xml to the original post?

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. The problem is likely in your public static void main method. Are you doing anything like this? 
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

 

 Using the autowiring would be within your other classes, but within your main method you'd want to do something more like appContext.getBean("UserManagerImpl");

Again, the autowiring would usually be within your classes, while you'd get beans from context otherwise.

Comment: No I'm not doing anything like this, I was thinking that if I put the spring.xml into WEB-INF/class, spring will automatically find the configuration file and register/initiate the beans. Is that assumption false? Also I didnt have a main file because I'm running a war. Only have my services class that call my manager.